# Dailymotion player : disable monetization?

Tags: dailymotion-api

Let's assume i am an advanced Dailymotion Partner : is there a way to disable monetization through the js API when building a dailymotion player ?

[This help center page](https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008943887-Enable-disable-the-monetization-on-your-videos) is dealing with a user interface process. I am looking for a dynamic way (player side) to enable / disable monetization based on user's context (subscriber vs regular user).

Saddly, nothing related in the [official documentation](https://developers.dailymotion.com/player/#player-runtime-parameters)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can manage on player side.

It's defined at video data level using the `advertising_instream_blocked` parameter ([documentation](https://developers.dailymotion.com/api/#video-advertising_instream_blocked-field))